# The class implementing ApplicationListener interface doesn't fire up when I create the event

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am trying to make account validation via email. I created an event class called `OnRegistrationSuccessEvent` that represents the event of a success registration.
I created a listener to handle this event called `RegistrationEmailListener` .
This is the code for the two classes:

`OnRegistrationSuccessEvent` class.

```
public class OnRegistrationSuccessEvent extends ApplicationEvent {

    private String appUrl;

    private User user;

    public OnRegistrationSuccessEvent(User user, String appUrl) {
        super(user);
        this.user = user;
        this.appUrl = appUrl;
    }

    // gettes and setters
}
```

`RegistrationEmailListener` class.

```
@Component
public class RegistrationEmailListener implements ApplicationListener<OnRegistrationSuccessEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private MailSender mailSender;

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RegistrationEmailListener.class.getName());

    public void onApplicationEvent(OnRegistrationSuccessEvent event) {

        logger.info("The rehistraton success event is fired up.");

        try {

            this.confirmRegistration(event);

        } catch (SendingEmailFailureException e) {

            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    private void confirmRegistration(OnRegistrationSuccessEvent event) throws SendingEmailFailureException {

        User user = event.getUser();

        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        userService.createVerficationToken(user, token);

        String recipent = user.getEmail();

        String subject = "Registration confirmation";

        String url = event.getAppUrl() + "/confirmRegistration?token=" + token;

        String message = "Thank you for regestring in our Tourists web app. Please click on the link below to complete your registration: ";

        SimpleMailMessage email = new SimpleMailMessage();

        email.setTo(recipent);

        email.setSubject(subject);

        email.setText(message + "http://localhost:8080" + url);

        mailSender.send(email);

        logger.info("Registration >>> Activation email is sent");
        logger.info("Recipient >>> " + recipent);
        logger.info("Text >>> " + email.getText());
    }
}
```

And I have a cntroller so I can test things out. with the following get request:

```
@GetMapping("/register")
    public String registerNewUser(WebRequest request) {

        User user = new User("bilal", "basiliusmourk@gmail.com", passwordEncoder.encode("bilal"), new Date());

        try {

            user.addAuthoriry(authorityService.getAuthority(AuthorityType.ROLE_TOURIST));

        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {

            logger.info(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {

            userService.registerNewUserAccount(user);

        } catch (UsernameAlreadyExistsException e) {

            logger.info(e.getMessage());

        } catch (EmailAlreadyExistsException e) {

            logger.info(e.getMessage());
        }

        String appUrl = request.getContextPath();

        logger.info("app url >>> " + appUrl);
        logger.info("publishing OnRegistrationSuccessEvent");

        eventPublisher.publishEvent(new OnRegistrationSuccessEvent(user, appUrl));

        //autoAuthentication(context, user.getUsername(), "bilal");

        logger.info("registration process completed for: " + user.getUsername());

        return "registrationSuccess";
    }
```

I made sure that the `OnRegistrationSuccessEvent` is really created. The problem is the listener has no idea that the event is launched, and I am not sure why. if anybody ca help i will be thankful.

Edit:
and that what my beans in the configuration class look like:

```
@Bean(name = "mailSender")
    public MailSender javaMailService() {

        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        javaMailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        javaMailSender.setPort(587);
        javaMailSender.setProtocol("smtp");
        javaMailSender.setUsername("myEmail");
        javaMailSender.setPassword("myPassword");

        Properties mailProperties = new Properties();

        mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
        mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.debug", true);
        javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(mailProperties);

        return javaMailSender;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {

        final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);

        return messageSource;
    }
```

logs:

```
Hibernate: insert into user_authority (user_id, authority_id) values (?, ?)
2019-05-29 04:03:54 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:384 - Done inserting collection: 1 rows inserted
2019-05-29 04:03:54 DEBUG JdbcCoordinatorImpl:183 - HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
2019-05-29 04:03:54 DEBUG ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner:236 - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner@78ae34f7: Adding task to queue -- com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@1f15b10c
2019-05-29 04:03:54 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:1801 - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@23b62cc3 [managed: 5, unused: 4, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@63544e3b)
2019-05-29 04:03:54 INFO  Class:98 - app url >>> /pfa-web-v2
2019-05-29 04:03:54 INFO  Class:99 - publishing OnRegistrationSuccessEvent
2019-05-29 04:03:54 INFO  Class:105 - registration process completed for: bilal
2019-05-29 04:03:57 DEBUG ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner:778 - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@692fae76 -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
2019-05-29 04:04:07 DEBUG ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner:778 - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@692fae76 -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
```

Comment: Make sure your listener is in a package that is covered by the component-scan o the `@SpringBootApplication`. I suspect it isn't detected.

Comment: This is exactly what it was. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me and couldn't find any problem with event listeners.
Double check your configuration and ensure event is getting triggered.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String registerNewUser() {

        eventPublisher.publishEvent(new OnRegistrationSuccessEvent(new User(), "http://localhost"));
        return "success";
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(new OnRegistrationSuccessEvent(new User(), "http://localhost"));
    }

}

class OnRegistrationSuccessEvent extends ApplicationEvent {

    private String appUrl;

    private User user;

    public OnRegistrationSuccessEvent(User user, String appUrl) {
        super(user);
        this.user = user;
        this.appUrl = appUrl;
    }

}

@Component
class RegistrationEmailListener implements ApplicationListener<OnRegistrationSuccessEvent> {


    public void onApplicationEvent(OnRegistrationSuccessEvent event) {
          System.out.println("confirmed");

    }

}

class User{

    private String userName;
}
```

logs:

```
2019-05-29 09:01:59.259  INFO 62832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-05-29 09:01:59.525  INFO 62832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-05-29 09:01:59.529  INFO 62832 --- [  restartedMain] com.barath.app.Application               : Started Application in 2.904 seconds (JVM running for 3.815)
2019-05-29 09:02:07.341  INFO 62832 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-05-29 09:02:07.341  INFO 62832 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-05-29 09:02:07.349  INFO 62832 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 8 ms
confirmed
```

Comment: Yes I made sure the event is triggered. it's the listener that doesn't respond.

Comment: Did you try above example? Does it work ? Enable the logs and share the log footprints. Is the publisher autowired ?

Comment: I had a hard time testing your example with my existing project. Since I work with just spring mvc and spring without spring boot. Regarding your other question, the publisher is correctly autowired yes.

Comment: @BilalEnnouali include the package names and try to autowire listener to find whether beans are created.

Comment: I made a silly mistake. The listener package was not included in the component scanning. Thanks your instructions helped a lot.